# Fan wiring with no wall switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan, fans

I am replacing a ceiling fan in my home built in 1999. The electrical box has four wires, black, white, blue, ground. I have no switch on my walls.

The old fan was controlled by a remote and we had issues getting the lights to work, hence the replacement. My fan has a remote and is how I plan to operate it. The instructions for the fan wiring can be found here on pg 10.

https://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/f1/f1521f17-4df1-4a12-b04c-26026838731f.pdf.

So, I have it wired as shown in the picture and now have an intermittent issue where when I turn on the fan from the remote, the fan pulses slightly. It does not get up to speed and giving it a manual push does not help get it going. The light also does not work when this occurs.[image: Wiring Picture]

I have tried attaching the blue wire to the black/red wires as well but with no success.

Thanks in advance for any help/ideas!

Comment: Do you have a meter to test the voltage from the black to the white and from the blue to the white? Do you have access to the space where the power wire (the "cable") is fed from? You must know which breaker controls this circuit to have shut off the power when installing the fan. How many other lights or receptacles are on this circuit? You may have a loose connection. If your switches and receptacles are wired using the "back stab" push in connectors, one of these may not be making good contact.

Comment: Yes, do you have a meter, especially one with a capacitance function?

Comment: Look at page 9 of your manual. Are you sure you have your addresses right?

Comment: Two other things to try. (1) Direct wire the fan for pull-chain control (without the remote). If it works as intended the problem is in the remote not the fan. (2) Recognize that both the fan pull-chain and the remote control speed by reducing the voltage on the line. Normally, for remote control you want the pull-chain set to "High".

Comment: Sounds like the new fan is a piece of junk.    On the old fan, were incandescent lights in use? Did it have a watt limiter device?

Answer (score 1):

Decades ago I installed several of those old Hunter oil bath fans (4-blade with low and high speed by pull chain) and have never had any problems with them. After 35 years of service I did have to replace the pull chain switch in the most heavily used one. All of these have light kits.

More recently I installed several of the newer cheaper Hunter 5-blade fans all with light kits in a relative's house (without remote transmitter/receiver) and they have not reported any problems.

More recently still in our house we got two additional fans--newer cheaper Hunter five-blade fans with remotes and we have had problems with both. After initially working, one fan would not turn on. In messing with it, I found that depowering the remote receiver by turning off the breaker (no wall switch) restored full function and it has continued to work since. High speed is a papers-off-the-desk tornado. Go figure!

The other fan no longer works on high speed. The medium and high buttons give the same speed. I am not even sure the medium is as fast as the medium on the other fan. Depowering the receiver did not restore function. "The next chance I get" I intend to disconnect the receiver and wire it directly to see if the problem is in the receiver or transmitter or is in the fan. All five of my fans are on the same circuit and all are powered direct with no wall switch.